# How do I track the progress of a task in Spark UI?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I would like to know how much is missing to complete a particular task in a spark Job. Mainly the whole job keeps running just because only one task(due data skew, another issue for another topic).

Is there any way to check the progress of an individual task through Spark UI?
[image]